# Find the rule: operation of 2 digits

Tags: mathematics

It is a math riddle(rule finding). A friend of mine asked me whether I can find a rule for following operation * (He said that he doesn't know the answer)

==============================================

92 * 56 = 45 
36 * 32 = 51 
84 * 28 = 40 
32 * 36 = 20 
92 * 81 = 90 
72 * 16 = 26 
88 * 54 = ?

==============================================

I have spent a few hours but couldn't find the rule.
The only thing that I found was that "multiplication of two numbers" always ends up with 52 (92*56 = 5152, 36*32 = 1152, 84*28 = 2352...and so on), but couldn't go further.

Can anybody guess what the rule is?

Comment: Hi Changhoon and welcome to Puzzling! Could you tell us where your friend found it, please? All questions on Puzzling that come from another source need to have their origin declared so the original author can get credit for creating it and we can be sure it isn't from an ongoing contest (which we're not allowed to help with). Please check the original source and list it in your question. Thanks, and happy Puzzling! :)

Comment: My friend said that he saw this from his company's intranet (Thereby He/I cannot share.the URL). The owner (one who posted the question on the intranet) didn't specify the source. I don't think it is from on-going contest, but I completely understand the rule. Sorry for bothering you guys.

Comment: Hey, it's no bother, and no need to apologise! :) We just need to be sure where puzzles like this come from before somebody can answer. If you click 'Edit' on this post and just write a line to explain this source, then if people feel that's enough explanation they will reopen the question and hopefully someone will be able to work it out. Watch this space!